# Simulating the range-based for loop's begin/end behavior

Tags: c++, c++11, foreach, c++14

Consider the specification of the range-based for loop's *begin-expr* and *end-expr* (N4140 [stmt.ranged]/p1). Given a range `__range` of type `_RangeT`,

> *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are determined as follows:
>
> - if `_RangeT` is an array type, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `__range` and `__range + __bound`, respectively, where `__bound` is
>     the array bound. If `_RangeT` is an array of unknown size or an array
>     of incomplete type, the program is ill-formed;
> - if `_RangeT` is a class type, the *unqualified-id*s `begin` and `end` are looked up in the scope of class `_RangeT` as if by class member access
>     lookup (3.4.5), and if either (or both) finds at least one
>     declaration, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `__range.begin()` and
>     `__range.end()`, respectively;
> - otherwise, *begin-expr* and *end-expr* are `begin(__range)` and `end(__range)`, respectively, where `begin` and `end` are looked up in
>     the associated namespaces (3.4.2). [ *Note*: Ordinary unqualified
>     lookup (3.4.1) is not performed. —*end note* ]

Is it possible to simulate this *exact* behavior in ordinary C++ code? i.e., can we write a `magic_begin` and a `magic_end` function template such that

```
for(auto&& p : range_init) { /* statements */ }
```

and

```
{
    auto&& my_range = range_init;
    for(auto b = magic_begin(my_range), e = magic_end(my_range); b != e; ++b){
        auto&& p = *b;
        /* statements */
    }
}
```

always have the exact same behavior?

Non-answers include qualified calls to `std::begin`/`std::end` (doesn't handle the third bullet, among other things) and `using std::begin; begin(range);` because, among other things, that is ambiguous if ADL for `begin` finds an overload that's equally good as `std::begin`.

---

For illustration, given

```
namespace foo {
    struct A { int begin; }; 
    struct B { using end = int; };
    class C { int* begin(); int *end(); }; // inaccessible
    struct D { int* begin(int); int* end();};
    struct E {};

    template<class T> int* begin(T&) { return nullptr; }
    template<class T> int* end(T&) { return nullptr; }
}

foo::A a; foo::B b; foo::C c; foo::D d; foo::E e;
```

I want `magic_begin(a)`/`magic_begin(b)`/`magic_begin(c)`/`magic_begin(d)` to be a compile error, and `magic_begin(e)` to return `(int*)nullptr`.

Comment: You mean, you want `magic_end` to be a compile error for `b`, right?

Comment: @Columbo Well, if we are following range-based for's spec, then both would be errors. But I'm happy with "at least one of `magic_begin` and `magic_end` result in an error".

Comment: Oh, sorry! Misread the second bullet point.

Comment: Can we assume that class types aren't `final`?

Comment: @Columbo Now you got me intrigued :) The ideal solution would work for both, but if you have one that works on all non-final classes I'll take it.

Comment: Is this important to you that magic_begin/magic_end return exaclty the same thing which begin/end would do? I mean - can magic functions return some "magic" iterator?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following SFINAE-friendly approach seems to work as desired (see below for exceptions):

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace detail {
    struct empty {};
    template <typename T>
    using base = std::conditional_t<std::is_class<T>{} && not std::is_final<T>{},
                                    T, empty>;

    struct P1 {typedef int begin, end;};
    template <typename U>
    struct TestMemType : base<U>, P1 {
        template <typename T=TestMemType, typename=typename T::begin>
        static std::true_type test_begin(int);
        template <typename T=TestMemType, typename=typename T::end>
        static std::true_type test_end(int);

        static std::false_type test_begin(float), test_end(float);
    };

    template <typename T>
    constexpr bool hasMember = !decltype(TestMemType<T>::test_begin(0)){}
                            || !decltype(TestMemType<T>::test_end(0)){};

    //! Step 1
    template <typename T, std::size_t N>
    constexpr auto begin(int, T(&a)[N]) {return a;}
    template <typename T, std::size_t N>
    constexpr auto end(int, T(&a)[N]) {return a+N;}

    //! Step 2 - this overload is less specialized than the above.
    template <typename T>
    constexpr auto begin(int, T& a) -> decltype(a.begin()) {return a.begin();}
    template <typename T>
    constexpr auto end(int, T& a) -> decltype(a.end()) {return a.end();}

    //! Step 3
    namespace nested_detail {
        void begin(), end();
        template <typename T>
        constexpr auto begin_(T& a) -> decltype(begin(a)) {return begin(a);}
        template <typename T>
        constexpr auto end_(T& a) -> decltype(end(a)) {return end(a);}
    }
    template <typename T, typename=std::enable_if_t<not hasMember<std::decay_t<T>>>>
    constexpr auto begin(float, T& a) -> decltype(nested_detail::begin_(a))
    {return nested_detail::begin_(a);}
    template <typename T, typename=std::enable_if_t<not hasMember<std::decay_t<T>>>>
    constexpr auto end(float, T& a) -> decltype(nested_detail::end_(a))
    {return nested_detail::end_(a);}
}

template <typename T>
constexpr auto magic_begin(T& a) -> decltype(detail::begin(0, a))
{return detail::begin(0, a);}
template <typename T>
constexpr auto magic_end  (T& a) -> decltype(detail::end  (0, a))
{return detail::  end(0, a);}
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c8514f56c017396). Note that GCCs lookup is broken as it doesn't consider non-type names for `typename T::begin` in `TestMemType::test_end/begin`. A workaround sketch can be found [**here**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8abb2f9761f4ea34).

The check in step 2 requires that the class type be derivable, which implies that this method doesn't properly work with `final` classes or unions - if those have an inaccessible member with name `begin`/`end`.

Comment: ...and unions. (And non-class types, but that's easy to fix.) Very nice though.

Comment: @T.C. Whoops, sorry. Fixed that non-class non-array bit.

Answer (score 1):

Almost.

Doing #1 if it works, and if not #2 if it works, and if not #3 is a pretty basic tag dispatching/sfinae exercise.

For #3:

Create a namespace that is used nowhere else.  Nest it in another.

In the outer, put a `=delete` begin function that takes anything.

Put a helper function that calls `begin` in it.

That will find the adl begin, and otherwise the deleted begin.

The failure mode is that the namespaces could be used somewhere else; there is no way to prevent it.

Comment: Well, #1 is trivial, but I'm not sure that how I can perfectly simulate #2, putting aside #3 for the moment. In particular, #2 says if the class has *any* member of any sort called `begin` or `end`, regardless of type or accessibility, then you try to do a member call, and don't attempt a free function call.

Comment: As to #3, I also thought of that idea. I guess it will have to be `void begin(...) = delete;`, so that we don't cause ambiguity with greedy templated overloads found by ADL. This still breaks if ADL finds a `begin(...);`, but given that such a function is nearly completely useless I guess I'm not too concerned about that.

Comment: @t.c. hmm.  So member var `begin` would `sizeof(T::begin)` work?  member, function, typedef... Work in this case includes fail to compile, as we can first check if `t.begin()` compiles and don't do that check.  Ie, find a pseudo-sfinae expression, and continue to 3 if it fails, and fail to compile if it succeeds *or* if it fails to compile.

Comment: So you want to induce a hard error if SFINAE finds `t.begin()` to be ill-formed, but `sizeof(T::begin)` succeeds? I don't think that handles non-static member functions (e.g., a `void begin(int)`). And in general I don't see how this can handle private members...

Comment: Actually, for step 3, I'm fairly sure a `void begin() = delete;` is sufficient. All we need to do is to teach the compiler that `begin` is a namespace scope function so that ADL can kick in; the signature found by unqualified lookup doesn't have to be viable. Still, step 2 is the blocker here.