# Is there a way to write a SFINAE test of "for-eachability" of a type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, for-loop, sfinae

I have used SFINAE expressions to test for if a type supports `operator<<`

```
namespace details
{
  template<typename T>
  struct sfinae_true : std::true_type
  {
  };

  template<typename T>
  sfinae_true<decltype (std::declval<std::ostream &> () << std::declval<T const &> ())> test_for_ostream (int);

  template<typename T>
  std::false_type test_for_ostream (long);
}

template<typename T>
struct supports_ostream : decltype (details::test_for_ostream<T> (0))
{
};
```

What I would like to test is if this a type `T` can be iterated over like this

```
for (auto && v : vs) {} // vs is T const &
```

The dilemma is that this is a statement and not an expression which makes it incompatible to use with `decltype`

I was thinking to use lambdas to convert a statement to an expression like this

```
auto x = [] () { for (auto && v : vs) {}; return 0; } (); // vs is T const &
```

However decltype of expressions containing lambdas seems to be explicitly forbidden:

```
// Won't compile in clang, gcc nor VC++
using x_t = decltype ([] () { for (auto && v : vs) {}; return 0; } ()); // vs is T const &
```

So that disqualifies it for use in a test function like this:

```
namespace details
{
  template<typename T>
  sfinae_true<decltype (
    [] () { for (auto && v : std::declval<T const &> ()) ; } () 
    )> test_for_container (int); 
  // Won't work because lambdas aren't allowed in unevaluated contexts

  template<typename T>
  std::false_type test_for_container (long);
}

template<typename T>
struct is_container : decltype (details::test_for_container<T> (0))
{
};
```

So I have run out of ideas, so I thought perhaps someone @Stackoverflow can come up with something interesting.

PS.

I can somewhat understand why `decltype ([] () {})` isn't allowed but `decltype ([] () {} ())` should always be well-defined ie `void`.

Comment: FWIW, my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32293860/simulating-the-range-based-for-loops-begin-end-behavior) is SFINAE friendly, i.e. checking the calls validity will work.

Comment: Hi, thanks. That would work. My own stab at it looked somewhat similar but did miss some cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the majority of cases the following trait should suffice:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <iterator>

namespace detail
{
    using std::begin;
    using std::end;

    template <typename T>
    auto is_range_based_iterable(...)
        -> std::false_type;

    template <typename T
            , typename I = typename std::decay<decltype(std::declval<T>().begin())>::type>
    auto is_range_based_iterable(int)
        -> decltype(std::declval<T>().begin()
                  , std::declval<T>().end()
                  , ++std::declval<I&>()
                  , void()
                  , std::integral_constant<bool,
                       std::is_convertible<decltype(std::declval<I&>() != std::declval<I&>()), bool>::value
                    && !std::is_void<decltype(*std::declval<I&>())>::value
                    && std::is_copy_constructible<I>::value
                  >{});

    template <typename T
            , typename I = typename std::decay<decltype(begin(std::declval<T>()))>::type>
    auto is_range_based_iterable(char)
        -> decltype(begin(std::declval<T>())
                  , end(std::declval<T>())
                  , ++std::declval<I&>()
                  , void()
                  , std::integral_constant<bool,
                       std::is_convertible<decltype(std::declval<I&>() != std::declval<I&>()), bool>::value
                    && !std::is_void<decltype(*std::declval<I&>())>::value
                    && std::is_copy_constructible<I>::value
                  >{});
}

template <typename T>
struct is_range_based_iterable : decltype(detail::is_range_based_iterable<T>(0)) {};
```

Test:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

int main()
{
    static_assert(is_range_based_iterable<std::vector<int>>::value, "!");
    static_assert(is_range_based_iterable<std::array<int, 5>>::value, "!");
    static_assert(is_range_based_iterable<int(&)[5]>::value, "!");
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f27b68f0d554dda5)

Comment: You don’t need to test for the `.begin()`/`.end()` members, the ADL-aware lookup of `begin()`/`end()` with the `std` versions in scope handles that nicely for you.

Comment: Hi. This answers the questions. I think I was secretly wishing for someway to use the `for` statement to test for it.

Comment: @LucDanton No. I can imagine myself [a container](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a13665c7c84235d) which is iterable through member functions `begin()`/`end()`, and whose namespace defines `begin()` and `end()` that, when found via ADL, won't let you enumerate the container's elements